# Docker COPY: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, copy

I'm trying to run a docker build which performs a maven build.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim

COPY * /myapp/src/

WORKDIR /myapp/src/

RUN mvn clean package

RUN ls -la target
RUN ls -la ./target

COPY ./target/myapp.jar ../
COPY config.yml ../

WORKDIR /myapp/

CMD ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

The issue I'm receiving is

```
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder185918822/target/myapp.jar: no such file or directory
```

I added the two `ls` statement for debugging purposes, this is the output:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-30T13:59:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Removing intermediate container 5c0f369c5f9d
 ---> d2b36b5070e3
Step 5/10 : RUN ls -la target
 ---> Running in 4de6062b1573
total 19104
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 classes
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 maven-archiver
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19538983 Oct 30 13:59 myapp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3294 Oct 30 13:59 original-myapp.jar
Removing intermediate container 4de6062b1573
 ---> 47f4a7534ffb
Step 6/10 : RUN ls -la ./target
 ---> Running in 55c68b1fbbe9
total 19104
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 classes
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct 30 13:59 maven-archiver
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19538983 Oct 30 13:59 myapp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3294 Oct 30 13:59 original-myapp.jar
Removing intermediate container 55c68b1fbbe9
 ---> bbc8a395474c
Step 7/10 : COPY ./target/myapp.jar ../
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder185918822/target/myapp.jar: no such file or directory
```

As you can see from the output of both `ls` commands, the jar file is there. Why is docker failing to find it?

Comment: It’s not in the host-system context that’s being passed into the build.  Do you want `RUN cp` instead?

Comment: Did you tried `COPY target/myapp.jar ../` instead of `COPY ./target/myapp.jar ../` ??

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze It seems to be working, thanks!